# A Word for Sharing an Unpleasant Experience

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word for that moment when you experience something unpleasant and feel obliged to share the experience with others?

For example, you taste something horrible and try to encourage others to try it so they can see just how disgusting it is. Or maybe look at something horrible and find yourself encouraging others to look, too.

I guess it's a more specific form of schadenfreude; but does it have its own word?

Comment: It depends on the reason why you want to share the unpleasant experience with others!!

Comment: Maybe better on [cogsci.se] (psychology)

Comment: There is the common idiom "*misery loves company*", but it's not a single word.

Comment: The word communion comes to my mind, however, that would not be restricted to bad experiences only...

Comment: Maybe 'communion in misery', but it's not a single word either...

Comment: "Oversharing" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think ***commiseration*** might fit your description.

Comment: Commiseration: the feeling or expression of pity or sorrow. How does it fit the context?